# Sendmail how to forward specific accounts to another server

Tags: email, sendmail

I have to linux mail servers running sendmail, both handling the same domainX.
server1 is declared as MX.
server2 is intended as a supplement that has more storage

I want server1 to handle all email for domainX as follows: 
user1: handled locally by server1
user2: handled locally by server1
user3: relayed to server2 and handled locally by server2

How can I achieve this with sendmail?

I know I can forward all mail for domainX to another SMTP server, but how do I do this for only some userY@domainX, but not all ?

Comment: Couple of choices - if the users are local you can set a `.forward` file in there home dir, if there not real users you can use `procmail` or something along those lines. If you need more info drop me a reply & i'll post a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround, it works for me, not entirely sure if it handles all possible situations properly.

- server1 handles mail for domainX
- server1 is declared with MX record in DNS
- server2 handles mail for domainX and server2

  ---
- server1 has user1, user2, user3
- server1 has user3

  ---
- server1 has in virtusertable `user3@domainX   user3@server2`
- server2 has in virtusertable `@server2        %1`

The scheme works as follows: 
`user1` and `user2` are handled locally by server1 according to default configuration.
`user3` is a virtualuser, translated to `user3@server2`, thus no longer processed locally, regardless of the existing local user `user3`.
server2 accepts mail for it's own hostname (specified explicitely).
All mail for all users `@server` are translated to local usernames. Mail for `user3@server2` is translated to local user `user3`.

*Of course, using prefixes to differentiate local accounts between multiple domains is possible.*